# Javascript code doesn't fire until the 2nd click for an html button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, event-listener

I'm learning javascript, and this simple piece of code just won't work the way I need it to.

All I need is to display the main tag at the click of a button. HOWEVER, it doesn't want to display until the SECOND click.

So the first click doesn't display the main. The second click does.

I've tried moving my coding around the html document (before/after body closing tag, etc).

I've looked through stack overflow, and similar questions don't really help my case. Or at least I don't understand how they can help me as a beginner.

```js
var aboutShow = document.getElementById("aboutLink");
aboutShow.addEventListener("click", displayMain);

function displayMain(){
  var mainSection = document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0];
  if (mainSection.style.display === "none"){
    mainSection.style.display = "grid";
  }
  else{
    mainSection.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
main{display:none;}
```

```html
<main> ... </main>
<button type="button" id="aboutLink">About</button>
```

There has to be something I'm missing that prevents that 1st click from firing the code. I mean, it seems simple enough???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var aboutShow = document.getElementById("aboutLink");
aboutShow.addEventListener("click", displayMain);

function displayMain(){
  var mainSection = document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0];
  if (mainSection.style.display || "none" === "none"){
    mainSection.style.display = "grid";
  }
  else{
    mainSection.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
main{display:none;}
```

```html
<main>text</main>
<button type="button" id="aboutLink">About</button>
```

Initially `mainSection.style.display` is empty, so it falls on the `else` part of the `if` statement and changes the property to `none`.
On the second click, the property now has the value of `none`, that's why it works on the second click.

[The HTMLElement.style property is used to get as well as set the inline style of an element.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

Answer (score 3):

`if (mainSection.style.display === "none")` is looking for an inline style tag, so instead of setting `display:none;` in your CSS, just set it inline on the element:

```js
var aboutShow = document.getElementById("aboutLink");
aboutShow.addEventListener("click", displayMain);

function displayMain(){
  var mainSection = document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0];
  if (mainSection.style.display === "none"){
    mainSection.style.display = "grid";
  }
  else{
    mainSection.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<main style="display:none;"> ... </main>
<button type="button" id="aboutLink">About</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

As has been answered, `mainSection.style.display` is empty. Another option is to get the [computed style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) of the element:

```js
var aboutShow = document.getElementById("aboutLink");
aboutShow.addEventListener("click", displayMain);

function displayMain() {

  var mainSection = document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0];
  if (window.getComputedStyle(mainSection).getPropertyValue('display') === "none") {
    mainSection.style.display = "grid";
  } else {
    mainSection.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
main {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<main> ... </main>
<button type="button" id="aboutLink">About</button>
```